# Segmentation fault error while installing opencv on raspberry pi 3. Any reason for that?

Tags: opencv, python-3, make

Hi everyone I hope someone could help solve this issue,I'm trying to install openCV 3.3.0 with python 3.5 on the raspberry pi 3 for the second time ( first time I got no module named cv2 ) but this time I didn't even got there , it seems like I'm blocked here with the error of 'segmentation fault' and i can't understand why !
this is what I typed in the terminal

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ source ~/.profile 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ workon cv 
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd opencv-3.3.0
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.3.0 $ cd build
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.3.0/build $ ls
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.3.0/build $ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE\
 -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
 -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.3.0/modules \
 -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
 -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3.5 \
 -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.5m.so \
 -D PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site- 
    packages/numpy/core/include \
 -D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site- 
   packages \
 -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
 -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
  Segmentation fault
```

Comment: What does the 'workon' command do?  I've never seen it before.

Comment: 'workon' is for the python virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

Could be running out of memory. Use htop to view cpu and ram usage when running command. Configure your RPI to add swap memory if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I did encounter this same scenario.

It was fixed when I change the uSD card, from **`8 GiB`** to **`16 GiB Class 10`** then re-image the new uSD card using latest raspbian.

Comment: thank you but I m using 32 Gib class 10 SD card with stretch on it so it's not the problem